# Grabbing the highest value from multiple fields in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am looking to have xslt grab every occurance of a field, in this case //field and then find the largest value held and output that.. would something like the below work? I have used something similair before but i am a little unsure on sort select'"value"

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count(//field1) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:for-each select="//field1">
            <xsl:sort select="value" order="descending" />
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

the xml will be in a format something like below

```
<1>
   <2>
       <field>125</field>
   </2>
</1>
<1>
   <2>
       <field>10</field>
   </2>
</1>
<1>
   <2>
       <field>0</field>
   </2>
</1>
```

(Not my choice of format for the XML, but it is what i have been dumped with to work with... in msot cases this field appears 28 times, but i always need the highest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about XSLT 2 but EXSLT provides `math:max`.

```
<h1>Max value is <xsl:value-of select='math:max(//field)' /></h1>
```

http://www.xmlplayground.com/3D3tUE

Comment: Perfect, using the math namespace has worked a treat, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `max()`...

```
<xsl:value-of select="max(//field)"/>
```

Comment: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Could not find function: max
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: max, 
i will have a look around for some examples of the field see if i missed anything

Comment: @JonathanSpickernell- You're not using an XSLT 2.0 processor. I suggest removing the 2.0 tag. Also, you can change your `xsl:sort` to `<xsl:sort select="." order="descending" />` and it should work.

Comment: As far as i am aware this is using XSLT 2.0 but i will remove and then double check whats running on the service.